# Multiple android Surface consumers - video playback to two surfaceviews

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, renderscript

I have this use case, where video from [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) has to be delivered to two [Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html)s. Unfortunately, whole Android Surface API lack's of that functionality (or at least, after studying developers site, I'm unable to find it).

I've had a simillar use case where the video was produced by a custom camera module, but after a slight modification, I was able to retrieve [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) from the camera so I just used lockCanvas, drawBitmap and unlockAndPost on two Surfaces. With MediaPlayer, I don't know how to retrieve Bitmap and keep playback with proper timing.

Also, I've tried to use [Allocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html) for that purpose, with one Allocation serving as USAGE_IO_INPUT, two as USAGE_IO_OUTPUT, and with ioReceive, copyFrom, ioSend methods. But it was also an dead end. For some unknown reason, RenderScript engine is very unstable on my platform, I've had numerous errors like:

```
android.renderscript.RSInvalidStateException: Calling RS with no Context active.
```

when context passed to RenderScript.create was *this* from Application class, or

```
 Failed loading RS driver: dlopen failed: could not locate symbol .... falling back to default
```

(I've lost full log somewhere...). And at the end, I was not able to create proper Input Allocation type to be compatible with MediaPlayer. Due to mentioned flaws with RenderScript on my platform, I would consider this as last resort for solving this issue.

So, in conclusion: How to play video (from mp4 file) to two Surfaces? This video has to be in sync. Also, more generic question, how to play video to #X Surface's which can be dynamically added, removed during playback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue by having multiple instances of [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) with same video file source. When doing basic player operations like pause/play/seek, I'm just doing them on every player.